# Induced Isomorphism between Homology Groups

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

How can I show the following isomorphism
$$H_n(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n-A) \cong H_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}, (\mathbb{R}^n-A) \times (-1,1) )$$

What I am trying for this problem is to use the following sequence, but I am not sure if this will help.

$$H_n(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n-A) \to H_n(\mathbb{R}^{n} \times \{0\}, (\mathbb{R}^n-A) \times \{0\} ) \to H_n(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}, (\mathbb{R}^n-A) \times (-1,1) )$$

Is it true that $\to$ are isomorphism between the homology groups

---

Comment: You have an homotopy equivalence of pairs between the two.

Comment: @Ahr No, I cannot understand. Can you give me some reference

Comment: A reference for the fact that homology is homotopy invariant? It's part of the Eilenberg-Steenrod axioms. I guess any standard reference on algebraic topology has those, the first one that comes to my mind is Switzer, but I guess Hatcher is perfectly fine.

Comment: You can see them here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eilenberg%E2%80%93Steenrod_axioms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the map of pairs $j : (\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A) \to (\mathbb{R}^{n+1}, (\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A) \times (-1,1)), j(x) = (x,0)$. Both the "absolute part" $j_{abs} : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ and the "relative part" $j_{rel} : \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A \to (\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A) \times (-1,1)$ are homotopy equivalences. Now consider the long exact sequences of the pairs $ (\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}, (\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A) \times (-1,1))$ which are connected by the homomorphisms $j_* : H_k(\mathbb{R}^n, \mathbb{R}^n \setminus A) \to H_k(\mathbb{R}^{n+1}, (\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A) \times (-1,1))$, $(j_{abs})_* : H_k(\mathbb{R}^n) \to H_k(\mathbb{R}^{n+1})$ and  $(j_{rel})_* : H_k(\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A) \to h_k((\mathbb{R}^n \setminus A) \times (-1,1))$. The last two of them are isomorphisms in all dimensions $k$ and therefore the five lemma shows that also $j_*$ is an isomorphism in all dimensions $k$.